# AWS Lambda image corrupted

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, image-processing, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm having an issue with AWS Lambda where my resized images become corrupted every few uploads. I wrote a script that pulls from S3 and resizes it into 3 sizes into another bucket, mostly with filestreams.  Here is the code:

https://github.com/handonam/AWS-Resizer/blob/493ff10c317e7150d1ac040f54065083963a9c67/createThumbnails.js

You can see the larger 512px upscaled file (the resized) along with the original (200px)

[image: Resizing to 512px]

And another resizing to 120px
[image: Resizing to 120px]

My lambda consumption looks totally fine for the most part. It is set up on the same region with 768mb memory and 20s timeout.  The scripts execute around 2 seconds using 90/768mb for small images (like 500px wide), or 14 seconds @ 648/768mb on much larger images such as 2000px wide. But even for a small image, the resize dies on me.  If I abandon filestreams and just write to buffer (just like the [aws example](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example-deployment-pkg.html)), then the image processing will end up with a buffer buffet, and lambda will use up way too many resources.

Any guidance is appreciated!

Comment: While I'll admit I am not proficient at what you are doing here, I do notice that at one point you call async.waterfall[ .. ... .. function transform(next) .... ... ... .. ..

 Seeing the colour highlighting throughout that section, I'm not quite sure if this bit of the code works as you expect.

Comment: @Uvar can you explain what you mean by the color highlighting?

Answer (score 1):

What's the chance your code is not threadsafe? i.e., some concurrent runs of the script collide? The corrupted file you show looks like it could have incorrect dimensions.

Comment: i'm only running the script once per image, where I'm uploading an image one at a time.

Comment: It may be true, but I would be worried anyway.  fs.writeFile('/tmp/object.jp2', response.Body, function(err) { the fille will exist across the calls and if one lambda is called twice it will damage the file.